# How to insert into Geography column using parameterized SQL

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlcommand

When I insert into a geography column with `geography::STPointFromText`, I have to dynamically build the column value, which ends up causing a SP:CacheMiss. My SQL cache is littered with singleton insert statements due to the way the insert is as we are repopulating this table every 15 min.  Is it possible to parameterize this during insert, so it is cached after the first insert?

Currently my code is below - I populate the table first with `NULL` in the geography column, then at the end, I update the whole table, setting the geography column at once.

```
$cn = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$cn.ConnectionString = "server='$sqlInstance';database='$sqlDb';trusted_connection=true;"
$cn.Open()

foreach ($loc in $locations) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Locations (vehicleID, Lat, Long, GeoLocation) 
            VALUES (@vehicleID, @Lat, @Long, NULL);"

    #$sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Locations (vehicleID, Lat, Long, KeyOn, avgSpeed, GeoLocation) 
    #        VALUES (@vehicleID, @Lat, @Long, geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST([@Long] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST([@Lat] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326));"

    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand ($sql, $cn)
    $cmd.Parameters.Add("@vehicleID", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).Value = $loc.vehicleId;
    $cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lat", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Decimal).Value = $loc.latitude;
    $cmd.Parameters["@Lat"].Precision = 18;
    $cmd.Parameters["@Lat"].Scale = 5;
    $cmd.Parameters.Add("@Long", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Decimal).Value = $loc.longitude;
    $cmd.Parameters["@Long"].Precision = 18;
    $cmd.Parameters["@Long"].Scale = 5;
    $reader = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
}

$sql = "UPDATE VZ.Locations SET [GeoLocation] = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST([Long] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST([Lat] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326);"
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand ($sql, $cn)
$reader = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$cn.Close()
```

If I uncomment the commented code that has the geography calculation as part of the insert, I get a SQL error saying `@Lat` and `@Long` are invalid columns.

Comment: Two answer your first question: you get a SP:CacheMiss because you're trying to build dynamic SQL queries: each statement has different text, so each statement hashes differently, so each statement gets a cache miss.

Comment: The error message is correct: `[@Long]` is not a column. Maybe you meant `@Long`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to construct the point text in PowerShell, e.g.:

```
$point = "POINT($($loc.longitude),$($loc.latitude))"
```

Then send that as a `@Point` parameter to your command to be inserted as:

```
geography::STPointFromText(@Point)
```

Doing that should solve both your SP:CacheMiss issue and the error messages about `[@Long]` and `[@Lat]` not being columns.